# Jquery is not getting triggered on select option

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown, and I want to trigger the jQuery function on selecting a value from the dropdown. However, the `change` event is not getting fired. `click` work, but it is being triggered twice.I want only the `change` event to be triggered.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" id="selcity">
  <h5>City</h5>
  <select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="city" id="city">
    <option label="Select City">Select City</option>
    <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#city').change(function() {
      console.log("Hello");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is working in your snippet. what is the issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because There is no fix to this question it is already working fine.

Comment: The code is working fine.

Comment: The code seems to be working absolutely fine. whats the issue then ?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the outer div `selcity` and not the select element `city`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
    jQuery('#city').change(function(){
        console.log("Hello");
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need recheck your id, I tried reproduce it worked.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
        jQuery('#city').change(function(){
            //console.log("Hello");
            $('#selected').text($(this).val());
        });         
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6" id="selcity">

     <h5>City</h5>

        <select class="chosen-select-no-single" name="city" id="city">

            <option label="Select City">Select City</option>

            <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
            <option value="Inchon">Inchon</option>


       </select>
       
       <p id='selected'></p>
    </div>
```